# SwiperJS web component + Vue 3 ignores observer param + event

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, web-component, swiper.js

I am importing SwiperJS WebComponent just fine in one of my Vue 3 SFC components.
It correctly shows some slides with clickable pagination and looping. Currently instantiated like this:

```
<swiper-container v-if="images.length" :loop="true" :pagination="{ clickable: true }" 
                  :observer="true" @observerupdate="console.log('Images changed: not working')">
     <swiper-slide v-for="img in images" :key="img.id">
         <img :src="img.src" alt="" />
     </swiper-slide>
</swiper-container>
<img v-else :src="defaultImage" alt="" />
```

- `images` correspond to an Array of image objects with their corresponding `id` and `src`.
- `defaultImage` correspond to a Vue ref with a default image.

This example just works fine, without the `observer` part.
But when `images` array changes, I would like it to refresh to reflect that changes. It is not happening. Moreover, `observerupdate` event is not firing when appropriate. Any ideas?

Here are the [observer](https://swiperjs.com/swiper-api#param-observer) param and the [observerupdate](https://swiperjs.com/swiper-api#event-observerUpdate) event documentation.

Comment: Like a failing car you bring back to the dealer; contact the vendor of SwiperJS: https://github.com/nolimits4web/swiper/issues

Comment: Haha, 184 issues and up. I changed to flicking carousel: https://naver.github.io/egjs-flicking/. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Too bad they support 6 Frameworks and not provide a native JavaScript Web Component ``<flick-it>``